Sublimetext - Go / Templ Syntax (2 Syntax in one File)
I would like to have a Sublime Text Plugin/Syntax for Templ Files.
Its already supported for a few IDEs like:

VSCode
nvim
vim
Emacs

its my first Sublimetext Plugin and im kinda Stuck. So here is what ive got so far:
I created a templ.sublime-syntax file in my User Folder:
%YAML 1.2
---
name: templ
file_extensions: [templ]
scope: source.go
extends: Packages/Go/Go.sublime-syntax
version: 2

contexts:
  prototype: # prototype/main
    - include: match-templ

  statements:
    - meta_prepend: true

  match-templ:
    - match: \btempl\s+([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_].*)
      scope: keyword.declaration.templ
      push: templ-content

  templ-content:
    - meta_content_scope: meta.function.templ
    - match: \n}\n\n
      pop: true
    - match: (?=\n}\n)
      pop: true
    - include: html-content
    - include: Packages/Go/Go.sublime-syntax#statements

  html-content:
    - match: <(?!\/)
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.begin.html
      push: html-tag
    - match: <\/[^>]+>(?!.*<\/[^>]+>) # match the last > if it starts with </
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true

  html-tag:
    - meta_scope: meta.tag.block.any.html text.html.basic
    - include: Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax
      scope: text.html.basic
    - match: '>'
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true
    - match: '/>'
      scope: punctuation.definition.tag.end.html
      pop: true

with this testfile.templ to test things out:
package templates

import (
  "gowiki/internal/templates/layout"
  "gowiki/internal/filemanager"
  "fmt"
)

func getFileList() ([]string) {
        all_files, err := filemanager.GetAllFiles()
        fmt.Println("all_files: ", all_files)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error fetching files:", err)
            all_files = []string{}
        }

        return all_files
}

templ Playground() {
    @layout.Base("Playground") {
        <h1>title</h1>

        <h1 class="mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl dark:text-white">Playground</h1>
        <div class="shrink-0">
        for _, file := range getFileList() {
            {{
                content, err := filemanager.ParseMarkdownToHtml(file)
                fmt.Println("err: ", err)
            }}
            <div class="markdown-content text-xl font-medium text-black">
                { content }
                <br/>
                <h1>asdf</h1>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    }
}


func getFileList2() ([]string) {
        all_files, err := filemanager.GetAllFiles()
        fmt.Println("all_files: ", all_files)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error fetching files:", err)
            all_files = []string{}
        }

        return all_files
}


templ Playground2() {
    @layout.Base("Playground") {
        <h1>title</h1>

        <h1 class="mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-5xl lg:text-6xl dark:text-white">Playground</h1>
        <div class="shrink-0">
        for _, file := range getFileList() {
            {{
                content, err := filemanager.ParseMarkdownToHtml(file)
                fmt.Println("err: ", err)
            }}
            <div class="markdown-content text-xl font-medium text-black">
                { content }
                <br/>
                <h1>asdf</h1>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    }
}

now onto my problems:

i cant exit the meta.function.templ Scope
i cant exit the meta.tag.block.any.html text.html.basic Scope
this leads to:

the first function getFileList() is properly highlighted
the rest of the file is html including the second go function getFileList2()


go in html isnt considered yet, should be something like this:

    # - match: \{
    #   embed: scope:source.go
    #   escape: \}
    #   scope: punctuation.section.block.begin.test
    # - match: \{{
    #   scope: punctuation.section.block.begin.test
    # - match: '@'
    #   scope: punctuation.section.block.begin.test
    # - match: \}
    #   scope: punctuation.section.block.end.test
    #   pop: true
    # - match: \}}
    #   scope: punctuation.section.block.end.test
    #   pop: true

maybe you got some ideas on where I went wrong with this.
Thanks for your help

I found a solution myself:
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Templ
file_extensions: [templ]
scope: source.go.templ
extends: Packages/Go/Go.sublime-syntax
version: 2

contexts:
  prototype:
    - include: match-templ

  match-templ:
    - match: \btempl\s+([[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_].*)
      scope: keyword.declaration.templ
      push:
        - meta_scope: meta.templ.block
          scope: text.html.basic
        - include: templ-content
        - match: '^}$'
          scope: punctuation.section.block.end.templ
          pop: true

  templ-content:
    - include: match-go
    - include: scope:text.html.basic

  match-go:
    - match: '{{'
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.begin.go
      push: go-embedded
    - match: '{'
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.begin.go
      push: go-embedded
    - match: '@'
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.begin.go
      push: go-embedded

  go-embedded:
    - meta_scope: source.go.embedded
    - include: pop-go
    - include: Packages/Go/Go.sublime-syntax

  pop-go:
    - match: '}}'
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.end.go
      pop: true
    - match: '}'
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.end.go
      pop: true
    - match: '{' # for the @
      scope: punctuation.section.embedded.end.go
      pop: true

The main Problem was the escape: - match: \n}\n\n which didnt work for some reason, with '^}$' it worked like a charm
